# AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, attributeerror, pyautogui

I Made a Simple Program using pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.write('Hello world!')
```

But when I run it I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/*****/Miscellaneous/Python projects/simple_pyautogui_program.py", line 3, in <module>
pyautogui.write('Hello world!')
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'write'
```

Is there a way to solve this or should I use pyautogui.press()?

Comment: Do you have a file of your own that is named `pyautogui.py`?  Show us the output of this code: `import pyautogui; print(pyautogui.__file__)`

Comment: How did you install the `pyautogui` module?

Answer (score 3):

1. pip install pyautogui
2. change file name to main.py

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. Reinstalling `pyautogui` solved it for me.

```
pip uninstall pyautogui  
py install pyautogui
```